# Find documents by object field inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I gotta a Show Schema and I want to get only avaible tickets inside a show. I need to find all documents that has availableTickets > 0 and get only this subdocuments with the show._id and show.title. How could I do it ?

```
// Show's Model

const mongoose = require('../../database/mongoose')

const ShowSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    startsAt: { type: Date, required: true },
    endsAt: { type: Date, required: true },
    openToBuyAt: { type: Date, required: true },
    closedToBuyAt: { type: Date, required:true },
    status: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    sectors: [{
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        availableTickets: { type: Number, required: true }
    }],
    convenienceFee: { type: Number, required: true },
    images: [
        { type: String }
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Show', ShowSchema)
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "tickets": [
        {
            "show._id": "ddadadas12a",
            "show.title": "Crazy Show",
            "sectors": [
                {
                    "name": "VIP"
                    "price": 50.25,
                    "availableTickets": 12
                },
                {
                    "name": "General Sector"
                    "price": 20.00,
                    "availableTickets": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have wrong schema.

You don't have "Available tickets" field. if you had any fields like say **availableTickets**

You could do this in easy way like this:

There are two main parts in this query:

1. Condition
2. Project fields: 0/1

`ShowSchema.find({availableTickets : { $gt: 0 }}, { title: 1, description: 0, startsAt: 0, endsAt: 0, openToBuyAt: 0, closedToBuyAt: 0, status: 0, sectors:1, convenienceFee:0, images:0, })`